# Oracle primary key with multiple column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, primary-key, alter-table

I have seen the below create table statement :

```
    create table cruise_orders
 (cruise_order_id number, 
order_date date, 
constraint pk_or_id primary key (cruise_order_id,order_date));
```

so here the primary_key has two columns. But in case if I try the below statement and try to alter the table cruise_orders and add the column order_date to the primary key pk_or_id it throws an error saying "A table can have only one Primary key".
So how does it works with the first statement ? and why it doesn't work with the second alter statement ?

```
create table cruise_orders
 (cruise_order_id number, 
order_date date, 
constraint pk_or_id primary key (cruise_order_id));
```

Comment: You cannot "add" column to the primary key, but need to drop current primary key constraint and create a new one

Comment: @mathguy. You are right. I misread the syntax diagram.

Comment: (In the example the date musn't be part of the key, of course. If the table is named `cruise_orders`, then `cruise_order_id` must be the primary key. If you added the date to it, you would just confuse everybody working with your database or reading your queries.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it so that the `cruise_order_id` must be unique and, separately, that the `order_date` must be unique then use two constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE cruise_orders(
  cruise_order_id NUMBER,
  order_date      DATE, 
  CONSTRAINT cruise_orders__or_id__pk PRIMARY KEY(cruise_order_id)
);

ALTER TABLE cruise_orders ADD CONSTRAINT cruise_orders__order_date__u UNIQUE(order_date);
```

---

If you really do want to have a single constraint with both columns the drop the first constraint and create a second with both columns:

```
CREATE TABLE cruise_orders(
  cruise_order_id NUMBER,
  order_date      DATE, 
  CONSTRAINT cruise_orders__or_id__pk PRIMARY KEY(cruise_order_id)
);

ALTER TABLE cruise_orders DROP CONSTRAINT cruise_orders__or_id__pk;

ALTER TABLE cruise_orders ADD CONSTRAINT cruise_orders__coi__od__pk
  PRIMARY KEY(cruise_order_id, order_date);
```

Then you will be able to have duplicate `cruise_order_id` values provided the `order_date` is different and vice-versa.